# Is direct RSA encryption of AES keys secure?

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes, attack, decryption

I am wondering: If we take this scheme/procedure and each of it seems very secure (to me at least), is it truly secure or is there a vulnerability hidden in the process?

This is the scheme:

Bob has an RSA key with modulo $N$ with a size that is considered safe, 2048 and a public power of $e=3$ (should assure efficient encryption).

Alice wants to send Bob a big file, and chooses symmetric encryption: She uses a random $k$ for AES and sends it encrypted using RSA using $C=k^e \bmod N$, and then sends the file encrypted by AES using key $k$.

To decrypt the file, Bob recovers $k$ using $k=C^d \bmod N$ and then decrypts the encrypted file using AES with $k$ is the key.

Is this procedure really secure?

On the paper, it uses secure parameters and seems secure, but I am not sure because $k$ is used too much here. Is there some hidden vulnerability I am missing here?

EDIT: what i am asking is in regards to attacking it, so could you please put an emphasize on attacking it rather than suggesting an alternative? i don't fully understand it, i understand that because of AES, $k^3$ cannot be more than 768 bits, so it does not pass the modulo (that is 2048). but i don't understand the technical details very well and would appreciate if you could elaborate on it instead of on possible mitigations.

thank you very much

Comment: This is trivially insecure because $k^3$ is at most 768 bit long whereas $N$ is 2048, so no reduction takes place and a simple cube root over the reals will yield $k$.

Comment: @SEJPM - could you please elaborate regarding the insecurity, the reduction that does not takes place and how to mathematically attack it to gain k? if possible not generally, so i can understand and better comprehend it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This scheme suffers from a classic problem of textbook RSA which is mitigated e.g. by RSA-KEM ([as outlined by kelalaka](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76857/23623)) or RSA-OAEP.

When you compute $k^3\bmod N$, you'll experience that $$c=k^3\stackrel{k< 2^{256}}{\leq}\left(2^{256}\right)^3=2^{768}\ll 2^{2000}<N$$

Now remember how $x\bmod N$ works: If $x\geq N$, then you recursively compute and return $(x-N)\bmod N$ and else you return $x$.

Given that $c\bmod N$ fits the "else" case, $c$ is simply returned. Now an adversary can just compute $\sqrt[3]c$ [as your calculator does for real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root#Numerical_methods) (with a bit more precision), you get $k$ back.

Note that the above weakness doesn't violate the RSA assumption because the assumption explicitly states that $x$ is uniformly randomly sampled from $\mathbb Z^*_N$ <sup>1</sup> in $c=x^e\bmod N$.

<sup>1: $\mathbb Z^*_N$ is the set $\{1,\ldots, N-1\}$ without any $x$ such that [$\gcd$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)$(x,N)>1$</sup>

Comment: your answer really helped me a lot in understanding why it is not secure. you've given me important fundamentals on understanding this weakness. thank you again for elaborating so much

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is a little away from the [RSA-KEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) (KEM : Key Encapsulation Mechanism). As [pointed out by SEjPM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76855/is-this-a-secure-encryption-scheme-rsa#comment170823_76855), in the comments, an AES-128 key when encrypted with the public modulus has almost 768 bits and this can be recovered by the [cube-root attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root). Here is the RSA-KEM;

RSA-KEM mitigates the attack that you have. RSA-KEM for a single recipient with AES-GCM simply as follows;

- **The Sender**;

  1. First generate a $x \in [2\ldots n-1]$ uniformly randomly, $n$ is the RSA modulus.
  2. Use a Key Derivation Function (KDF) on $x$, $$key= \operatorname{KDF}(x)$$ for AES 128,192,or 256-bit depending your need.
  3. Encrypt the $x$, $$c \equiv x^c \bmod n$$
  4. Encrypt the message with AES-GCM genenerate an $IV$ and $$(IV,ciphertext,tag) = \operatorname{AES-GCM-Enc}(IV,message, key)$$
  5. Send $(c,(IV,ciphertext,tag))$
- **The receiver**;

  1. To get $x$, They are using their private key $d$,$$x = c^d \bmod n$$
  2. Uses the same (KDF) on $x$ to derive same AES key, $$key= \operatorname{KDF}(x)$$
  3. Decrypts the message with AES-GCM $$message = \operatorname{AES-GCM-Dec}(IV,ciphertext,tag, key)$$

**Note 1:** If you want to send the key itself as you described, to prevent the attacks on textbook RSA, you will need a padding scheme like OAEP or PKCS#v1.5. RSA-KEM eliminates this by using the full modulus as a message.

**Note 2:** The above described RSA-KEM work for a single-user case. As noted by [Fgriei on comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76855/is-this-a-secure-encryption-scheme-rsa#comment170830_76857) RSA-KEM for multiple user will fall into [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad's_broadcast_attack). Instead using RSAES-OAEP makes it safe for multiple recipients with the same $x$ encrypted for different recipients. This will make it very useful to send the message multiple recipients instead of creating a new $x$ for every recipient and encrypting the message for each derived key (as PGP/GPG does).

Comment: Note: using RSAES-OAEP makes it safe to send the same $k$ encrypted to multiple recipients, which in turn is handy to have the bulk of the ciphertext common to all recipients (as PGP/GPG does). RSA-KEM does not, for it would fall to [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad's_broadcast_attack).

Comment: @alberto123 Since the exponentiation with 3 did not pass the modulus, there is no modulus operation and the value of the ciphertext can be found by cube-root algorithms. Cube calculation is easy  ([cube-root attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_attack)). To mitigate this a good padding scheme is necessary.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks. Added as 2. note with some clarification.

Comment: thank you very much for answering me @kelalaka. you've both complimented each other and i learnt a lot from both answers. i feel that the answer who gave me the most tools to understand the matter was SEJPM's one, so i marked him. however, i learnt a lot from your answer to apply the correct measures and how to fix the problem. thank you very much